# Error codes while form validation in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is there a nice and clean way to use custom error codes while form validation? Eg:

```
{
    "name": {
        "code": 121,
        "message": "This field can't be blank."
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "name": ["This field can't be blank."]
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the error message in the `__init__` method of your serializer:

`self.fields['field_name'].error_messages['error_message_key'] = your_custom_error`

You can find all error_messages keys related to each Field in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#built-in-field-classes). For instance, CharFields error message keys are *required, max_length, min_length*.

If you're using [custom field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#error_messages) from DRF:

```
name = serializers.CharField(
    ...,
    error_messages={error_message_key: your_custom_error}
)
```

If you want to raise more specific errors, I encourage you to take a look at [Raising ValidationError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror) from the official documentation and [ValidationError](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror) from DRF documentation.

Comment: This does not work. DRF requires string, not a dict => "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'"